# How to add the verification panel in the IZpack installer

Tags: izpack

How to add the verification panel in the IZpack installer?

We need to add one panel more to verify that the customer filled the details and only after that it will generate one OTP...

Give some suggestions on how to implement effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you mean is that you want to add a non-standard "verification" panel to your installation (since IzPack has no "verification panel"). For this you need to create a **Custom Panel**, for which there is abundant documentation.

Please see [here](http://izpack.org/documentation/creating-panels.html).